# To Fix HTTP 400-499 error codes with 301 redirects in .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This issue is on WordPress site.

I am aware we can change the URL naming convention in WP but I have changed my URL format from date format to simple postname followed by slug as shown below.

Old style:

```
www.example.com/2013/02/09/rin​gdroid
```

New style:

```
www.example.com/rin​gdroid
```

Google previously indexed my websites pages (*sitemap.xml*) with below format:

```
www.example.com/2013/04/18/hot​test-gadgets-of-2013-to-include-in-​your-list
www.example.com/2013/02/09/rin​gdroid
```

I have resubmitted the sitemap but there are still 404 errors in Google/Bing engine.

Could you please help me to write 301 redirects rule in *.htaccess* file so when someone clicks the URL for:

```
www.example.com/2013/02/09/rin​gdroid
```

They should be redirected to:

```
www.example.com/rin​gdroid
```

How we can write rule in *.htaccess* file to remove date part `2013/02/09/`?

I tried something like this (Googled it), but it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$4 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The `NC` flag and `RewriteBase` directives are not required here. This could also be "simplified" as `RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` - no need for the additional capturing groups and this now matches the exact URL as given, no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+/){3}(.*)$ /$2 [R=301]
```

This will strip any sequence of 3 numbers each followed by slashes (so it will work with short year dates like YY/MM/DD dates or single digit days/months like 2013/2/9. If you want to keep the date in the url and have it silently redirect to the correct page without the user knowing, lose the `[R=301]`

Comment: also, is this for a wordpress site? If so it would be better to manage your url naming within the wordpress options than to go writing your own htaccess rules.

Comment: Hi WebChemist , Really thankful giving an idea how to implement it. I tried your suggestion but Url its was returning as www.domain.com/ringdroid/02/09/rin​gdroid. so i have implemented my below own code and here it is.

Comment: This regex _should_ have worked as intended IMO, however, the missing `L` flag might have been the problem. The rewriting will have continued, so would have at least got caught in the WordPress "front controller" that presumably followed.